# Why does one of my login functions work and the other does not, despite the fact that they both have the identical code?

Tags: python, function, file, text

So I am trying a login system for my bank management project and I created two of the login system.
one for the admin system and the other for the customer. This is the code and text file for both. Why would my first function work and not the second?  FYI I can't use any global function and dictionary and the error I been getting is ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
def LAdminAccount():
EnteredStaffAccountNumber = str(input("========== Please Type in Your Account Number:"))
EnteredStaffPassword = str(input("========== Please Type in Your Password:"))
A= open("AdminUser.txt","r")
for line in A.readlines():
    us,pw = line.strip().split("|")
    if (EnteredStaffAccountNumber == us ) and (EnteredStaffPassword == pw):
        print ("Login successful")
        A.close()
        AdminMenu()
print ("Wrong username/password")
return
def LCustomerAccount():
EnteredID = str(input("========== Please Type in Your Account ID:"))
EnteredPassword = str(input("========== Please Type in Your Password:"))
B= open("Customerlogin.txt","r")
for line in B.readlines():
    id,pw = line.split("|",1)
    print (id)
    print (pw)
    if (EnteredID == id ) and (EnteredPassword == pw):
        print ("Customer Login successful")
        B.close()
        CustomerMenu()
print ("Wrong Account Number/password")
menu()
```

### AdminUser.txt

00001|1234

### Customerlogin.txt

000403100865|3088

## Output is:

### 000403100865

### 3088

### Customer Login successful

### Wrong Account Number/password

Comment: Both pieces of code look identical, and share a name?

Comment: Isn't a `.strip()` missing in `id,pw = line.split("|")` on second code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests that the problem is the following line:

```py
id,pw = line.split("|")
```

If you have more than one "|" in your text your will not be able to split them this way.

To guarantee the string is split at most once try replacing with:

```py
id,pw = line.split("|", 1)
```

Comment: thanks for the help but even I change it to split 1 it still doesn't work and just display ("Wrong Account Number/password")

Comment: ok, that's a different issue: add some prints to see the exact values of `id` and `pw`. Add these to the question

Comment: also, to simplify try to replace the file with a list of strings so it's easier to test it without having your file